# Simple Interrupt Handling/ Multi-threading program?

Tags: c, multithreading, embedded, interrupt-handling, serial-communication

I'm new to Embedded programming and multi-threading and I'm trying to understand how Interrupt handlers work in different contexts/scenarios. For the current question, I just want to know how a interrupt handler would work in the following scenario.

We have a data stream coming from a RS232 interface that is processed by some microcontroller. An interrupt handler(of void type) has a `read()` function which reads the incoming data bytes. If a character is detected then the interrupt handler invokes a function called `detectString()` which returns `TRUE` if the string matches the reference string which is "ON". If `detectString()` returns `boolean TRUE` it invokes a function called `LED_ON()` which should turn on an LED for 1 minute. If it returns false it should turn off the LED. Lets say the microcontroller has a clock frequency of 20MHz and an addition operation taken 5 clock cycles.

My questions are as follows

How do we approach this problem with an FSM?
The RS232 interface keeps transmitting data even after the LED is turned on. So am I correct in assuming that the interrupt handler should work with a one thread and the functions that it invokes should work from a different threads?
How would a skeletal program implementing this FSM look like? (a C pseudocode might really help to understand the backbone of the design)

Comment: An accurate answer needs more information: "multi-threading" implies an RTOS.  What vendor and version? Or are you working with a bare-metal application? In that case, the answer depends on several of your implementation choices, i.e. your scheduler, interrupt priority settings, etc.

Comment: @Throwback1986 Yes, consider any microcontroller with RTOS that is suitable for implementing this functionality. I'm just trying to understand/learn the logic and not the full implementation details.

Comment: More details needes. An RTOS can be anything from a simple scheduler/coop-multitasking to Linux with RT-extensions. Also it depends on the interrupt-handling: ISR directly for the hardware, deferred interrupt handler, combination? Which capbilities does the hardware provide (DMA, single-symbol IRQ)? What exactly does the protocol specify? You might notice: the question is too broad for this forum.

Comment: @Olaf This is more like an open ended problem intended to test the way the algorithms is formulated rather than coming up with a working program targeted for a specific micro-controller. But, one additional detail that was mentioned was since OS is involved there there is no mutex or locks.

Comment: @Naveen: This is actually a problem which is very depending on the underlying hardware (heck, there is little more hardware-depending than interrupt handling an peripheral service).So you cannot seperate a solution from the hardware here. That is a basic thing to understand when working with embedded systems. From your question, I get the strong impression you really should get the basic priciples and terms right first. You seem to confuse multithreading, interrupts, etc. - no offense!

Comment: Does you OS support waiting on an event/semaphore with a timeout?  If so, what you seem to want is pretty easy.

Comment: What does the processor's clock speed or the number of cycles an addition operation takes have to do with the problem? In my opinion, you should model the FSM without thought to the interrupt handler. One of the event types that the FSM should handle is characters received over the UART. Once you have your FSM model, you can decide how to implement it on your platform.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Since every addition operation takes 5 cycles it can be used to implement a counter for timing the LED_ON duration to 1 minute.

Comment: @Naveen: I see - I had assumed that there would be an actual hardware timer to deal with the timing.

Comment: @Naveen Assuming that you are using an OS/RTOS (by virtue of the "multithreading" statements), simple instruction cycle counts cannot be used to produce any sort of meaningful timer.  A timer interrupt (i.e. systick, etc.) is the usual practice for timing.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing this in an interrupt handler, why would you need different threads? It shouldn't matter what else you're doing, as long as interrupts are enabled.

As for FSM, I wouldn't call a "detect_string". RS232 is going to give you one character at a time. It's possible your UART interrupts you only when you've received more than one, but there's usually a time component as well so it would be unwise to count on that. Make your FSM take one input character at a time. Your states would be something like:

```
=> new state = [Init] (turn LED off if on)

Init: (Get 'O') => new state = [GotO]
Init: (Get anything else) => new state = [Init]
Init: (Timer expires) => who cares? new state = [Init]

GotO: (Get 'N') => new state = [GotON] (turn on LED, set timer)
GotO: (Get anything else) => new state = [Init]
GotO: (Timer expires) => who cares? new state = [GotO]

GotON: (Get anything) => who cares? new state = [GotON]
GotON: (Timer expires) => turn LED off, new state = [Init]
```

Obviously lots of tinkering you could do with details, but that's the general idea.

Comment: That depends on the system architecture and the actual protocol. For instance, the FSM might have to be split over multiple interrupt handlers.

Comment: @Olaf Why multiple interrupt handlers?

Comment: Depends on the architecture and interrupt handler. For instance you might need timeouts using a timer interrupt, some MCUs have different interrupts for receive, transmit and error handling (receive errors must be anticipated), you could transfer per DMA, etc. See my other comment, too.

Answer (score 2):

A preemptive kernel will usually provide the ability for an interrupt to set an event that a higher priority thread is pending on.

As for the interrupts, one way of implementing something like a state machine is to use nested pointers to function, similar to an asynchronous callback, but with optional nesting: For example:

```
typedef void (*PFUN)(void);
/* ... */
PFUN pFunInt = UnexpectedInt;   /* ptr to function for interrupt */
PFUN pFunIntSeqDone;
/* ... */
void DoSeq(void)
{
    pFunIntSeqDone = IntSeqDone;
    pFunInt = IntStep0;
    /* enable interrupt, start I/O */
}
void IntStep0(void)
{
    pFunInt = IntStep1;
    /* handle interrupt */
}
void IntStep1(void)
{
    pFunInt = IntStep2;
    /* handle interrupt */
}
void IntStep2(void)
{
    /* done with sequence, disable interrupt */
    pFunInt = UnexpectedInt;
    pFunIntSeqDone();    /* call end action handler */
}
void IntSeqDone(void)
{
    /* interrupt sequence done handling code */
    /* set event for pending thread */
}
void UnexpectedInt(void)
{
    /* ... error handling code */
}
```